# Isotope responsive size problems when filtering

Tags: resize, responsive, bootstrap-4, jquery-isotope

I'm having a problem with [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/).
Everything seems to work except that, when I filter the items, these are resized in a weird way, as if the items were resized relative to their old width instead of the container width.

I let you see by yourself here : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLPbpd (Click on the group of red buttons to see).

I tried to layout after each filter :

```
$iso.isotope('layout');
```

and to destroy isotope and then re-init, but nothing solved it.

My `.grid-sizer` is at the perfect size and all items have the same width..

I really don't know what could be wrong there, so I'd be very thankful if you could help me !

Sorry for my bad English, it's not my main language !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

The problem was due to

```
fitWidth: true,
```

in the *initialization code* of Isotope.

I just removed it and it works.